# vim script to insert ascii-art formulas

Tags: formula, vim, maxima, ascii-art

I try to use Vim as much as I can to learn it.
Today I had to write lots of mathematical functions. I wrote them like `f(x)=e^(x/sqrt(x))` (nonsensefunction for example) but this is very hard to read.

My idea was to use the console output of maxima and insert it in the text to get something like:

```
             x
          -------
          sqrt(x)
f(x) := e
```

which is very easy to read.

I already know a lot of maxima commands so it would be very easy and productive for me to write formulas in the maxima syntax and get them in this wonderful output :)

I had absolutely no experience with vimscript. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i use this in my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
 " calls maxima --very-quit -r "[ARG];"
 function! AsciiMath(formula)
   let cmdln='maxima --very-quiet -r "'.a:formula.';"'
   let @a=system(cmdln)
   if !v:shell_error
 "    echo @a
     put a
   else
     echo '"'.a:formula.'" is an invalid maxima expression"'
   endif
 endfunction
```

and call it like:
`:call AsciiMath("f(x):=e^(x/sqrt(x))")`

i think the function is straght forward to understand, but there are some tricky parts:

- `put` requires a register as argument see `:h registers` and `:h put`
- arguments cannot be used like `formula` they need the prefix
  (namespace) `a:` use it like `a:formula`.
- if you have vim configured
  to reload the `.vimrc` file then you should use `function!` instead
  of `function` because otherwise you 'll get an error (something like
  "[FUNCTIONNAME]  is allready defined")
- `system()` returns the console output of its argument as returnvalue and puts the         returnvalue of its argument in `v:shell_error`.

Comment: You can use `:put` with the expression register.  This way, you use a local variable instead of a global register:  first `let a=system(cmdln)`, then test `v:shell_error`, and then `put=a`.

Comment: If i replace @a with f.e. myvar then it doesnt work. I read :h put and it says that you should use a register. I thought with @a i use the register a, right? Did i missunderstood something?

Comment: I suspect that you did not test my example.  I used `a` as the variable, but you could use `myvar` instead.  Since you do not believe me, try reading `:help @=`.  The last line mentions using the expression register with the `:p` command.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have an external command that returns the (rendered formula) output to *stdout*, the `:read! {cmd}` command will insert the output (below the current line or at the prepended `[range]`:

```
:read! maxima --very-quiet -r "formula"
```

You can make a custom command for this, too:

```
:command! -nargs=1 -range Maxima execute '<line1>,<line2>read! maxima --very-quiet -r' shellescape(<q-args>, 1)
```